# ng-Options edit options - AngularJS

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

So I have an `AngularJS` form with a `select` option to create an `restaurant` in my `DB`;

```
<div id="name-group" class="form-group" ng-init="getClasses();">
    <div class="select-wrapper">
        <label for="location">Resaurant Class</label>
        <select name="class" ng-model="formData.class" ng-options="class.id as class.name for class in classes track by class.id">
            <option value="">-- Select Class --</option>
        </select>
    </div>
</div>
```

From the above, I'm getting the `classes` and then listing them. Because I have `track by class.id` it means I can have a `default` option as it doesn't have a `value`. All good here.

Now to edit this `restaurant`, I retrieve it from the `DB` and it will have whatever class I have saved for it from the above form. This is the `id` of the `restaurant class`.

So `restaurant.restaurant_class_id = class.id`

Now when I retrieve the `restaurant`, using the code below I'm able to load the form and the `restaurant class` will be selected correctly;

```
<div id="name-group" class="form-group" ng-init="getClasses();">
    <div class="select-wrapper">
        <label for="location">Resaurant Class</label>
        <select name="class" ng-model="restaurant.restaurant_class_id" ng-options="class.id as class.name for class in classes track by restaurant.restaurant_class_id">
            <option value="">-- Select Class --</option>
        </select>
    </div>
</div>
```

Notice the `track by restaurant.restaurant_class_id`. This is the desired behaviour.. Load the `form`, load the `restaurant`, load the `restaurant classes`, and automatically set the corresponding `restaurant class` in the dropdown.

Now the problem is when I then want to select another `restaurant class` for the `restaurant`. This results in an `undefined` value.

If I remove `track by restaurant.restaurant_class_id` and replace it with `track by class.id` two things happen;

1. The `restaurant class` is not selected. So I end up with `-- Select Class --` displayed which is the default
2. If I select a `restaurant class` from the drop down then the value is set correctly.

I'm using `ng-inspector` to check what value is being set on the `$scope`

So I guess my question is how can I select the correct `restaurant class` based on what is retrieved from `DB` and be able to change it without getting `undefined` value.

Any guidance from `Angular` gurus appreciated.

Comment: This should happen with model itself. I have done it yesterday with model. :-)

Comment: You mean `ng-model`?

Comment: Yes. Db value automatically selected by model. Check whether u have another issue

Comment: You're right! I removed `track by` and it works now

Comment: Great!!!! Pleasure to help u

Answer (score 0):

Yes. Db value automatically selected by model. Check whether u have another issue